# Is onbeforeunload considered correct when also using angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onbeforeunload

I need to execute `logout()` function if user closes or refreshes page.
I am using Angular.js library, and i need to broadcast that user left even if he doesnt click the proper button for that.

Should i just go with `onbeforeunload` or is there something in Angular.js i overlooked ?

Edit : I would like to avoid adding another module/library

Comment: Does this question / answer help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777890/equivalence-of-window-onbeforeunload-in-angularjs-for-routes

Comment: Well, sort of.But I would like to avoid adding another library/module

Comment: I'm not sure what that answer has to do with adding another library / module.  I read it as being part of AngularJS.  This is a good read too (and the one I was originally looking for): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22663009/angular-user-logoff-on-closing-window#comment34522826_22663009

Comment: Thats because it has been removed from the core library and its now a separate module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use websockets for that (nodejs example):

```
socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    // do server stuff here
});
```

You are not guaranteed to handle this from client side, because user can simply close browser. another way is to use ajax to notify server "hey i'm online" with interval of time. if server stops receiving notification, that means user went offline (websockets are better way)

Comment: Most application servers should have a way to run code on a session timeout.

Comment: @JeffryHouser how can server know if the user closes a browser? session timeout is different thing

Comment: A server cannot know if a user closes a browser.  However, closing a browser will let the session time out in most cases.  In practical application that has been good enough for all uses cases I've needed to cover.